# Преобразование синхронного соединения через httpURLConnection в асинхронное через HttpClient

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, асинхронность

Есть синхронный метод, сделанный на httpURLConnection, и его надо преобразовать в асинхронный вариант. Основной синхронный метод полностью функционален, работает стабильно. Чтобы переделать его в асинхронный, я пытаюсь использовать HttpClient с его нативным senAsync() методом (JDK11). Но я дошел до того момента, где не знаю, что дальше. Ступор.

Общий проект такой:
1) Есть несколько тестовых классов, который экстендят класс abstractAPITest, который, понятное дело, абстрактный. 
2) Этот абстрактный класс содержит метод, который создает подключение, над которым я как раз работаю в данный момент.
3) Класс User, вызывающий тестовые классы
4) Класс Main, который создает юзеров в нескольких threads.

Возможно, стоит перенести вызов соединения в класс User или в Main? Не знаю, как лучше.

Вот оригинальный синхронный код:

```
byte[] sendRequest(JSONObject jsonObject, String username, String password) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(this.apiUrl)).openConnection();
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()));
        }
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        log.info("REST send: JSONObject");
        if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            log.error("REST send error");
            throw new IOException();
        } else {
            byte[] responseBody = null;
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data.append(line);
                responseBody = data.toString().getBytes();
            }
            br.close();
            return responseBody;
        }
    }
```

И асинхронный вариант, который я смог реализовать пока что (естественно, он пока не работает, и я не могу разобраться, что с ним сделать, чтобы заработало):

```
byte[] request = jsonObject.toString().getBytes();

        String userPassword;
        if (username != null && password != null) {
        userPassword = username + ":" + password;
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Нет логина и/или пароля.");
    }

    byte[] responseBody = null;
    byte[] request = jsonObject.toString().getBytes();

    var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    var httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(new URI(apiUrl))
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(request))
            .build();

        HttpResponse.BodyHandler<String> bodyHandler = HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString();

        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> future = client.sendAsync(httpRequest, bodyHandler);
        future.thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println)
                .join();

            byte[] responseBody = null; // DON'T PAY ATTENTION 
            return responseBody;        // TO THESE TWO LINES
        }

        private static String basicAuthorization(String username, String password) {
            String userPassword = null;
            if (username != null && password != null) {
                userPassword = username + ":" + password;
            }
            return "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes());
        }
```

В общем, надо, чтобы асинхронный метод делал то же самое, что и синхронный, только... извиняюсь за тавтологию - асинхронно.
А именно: отправляет на сервер JSON запрос, преобразованный в массив byte, а затем принимает JSON ответ от сервера. Чтобы функционал был 1 в 1, но асинхронно.
И я ума не приложу, как это сделать.

Comment: a зачем отправлять запрос асинхронно, если предполагается из метода возвращать byte[], а для этого все равно нужно заблокировать текущий thread, чтобы дождаться ответа. Серверу тоже все равно, синхронный запрос был или асинхронный.

Comment: Требование начальства)

Comment: обычно начальство требует чего-то осязаемого, а здесь разницы никакой не ощущается. Вы справшивали, зачем ему это нужно? Может, ему нужно чего-то другого?

Comment: Да, смысл в нагрузочном тестировании. Имитируется одновременное подключение огромного числа пользователей, которые совершенно случайно отправляют на сервер различные запросы. Даже если имитировать пользователей в разных тредах, все равно в целом получается, что подключения происходят последовательно, то есть синхронно. И сервер с таким справляется легко. Но это не отражает реальной ситуации, когда одновременно могут подключаться разные пользователи. Отсюда и требование к асинхронности, чтобы эту "одновременность" сымитировать.

Comment: "Даже если имитировать пользователей в разных тредах, все равно в целом получается, что подключения происходят последовательно"  - нет, если вы запустите 1000 потоков (а это легко сделать), то у вас будеи 1000 параллельных запросов. Если по факту они происходят последовательно, то ктот-то эту последовательность обеспечивает, какая-то часть программы, о которой вы не сказали. Если метод sendRequest будет делать асинхроннй запрос, но по прежнему возвращать byte[], то общее поведение программы не изменится, запросы по прежнему будут происходить последовательно.

Comment: а при чем тут byte[]? что оно должно возвращать, чтобы добиться асинхронности? Ну и 1000 потоков - с асинхронностью это же не связано, т.к. поток, отправивший запрос, блокируется, а смысл асинхронности в том, что в потоке 1 запрос отправляется, в потоке 2 создается ожидающий ответа элемент, и поток 1 не блокируется, и продолжает выполнение программы, а когда приходит ответ от сервера, ожидающий элемент в потоке 2 ловит его и выполняет свою задачу.

Comment: я же написал - чтобы  из метода возвращать byte[], нужно заблокировать текущий thread, и тогда поведение метода будет точно таким же, как если бы он использовал синхронный вызрв.

Comment: Но раз текущий thread блокируется - это уже не асинхронность.

Comment: смысл асинхронности в том, что в качестве параллельной активности используется не thread, занимающий много памяти (0.5-1.0 Мб), а асинхронная процедура, занимающая менее килобайта. Это позволяет запускать миллионы параллельных активностей вместо тысяч. Другого смысла у асинхронности нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95121/discussion-between-rfq-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Что-нибудь вроде

```
HttpResponse.BodyHandler<byte[]> bodyHandler = HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray();

CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<byte[]>> future = client.sendAsync(httpRequest, bodyHandler);
HttpResponse<byte[]>> response = future.get();
byte[] responseBody = response.body();
return responseBody;
```

Comment: Вот оно мне пишет то же, что и везде - что бы я ни делал: "future: "jdk.internal.net.http.common.MinimalFuture@cb6e04d[Not completed] (id=9)"", то есть фьючер не выполняется, в итоге ответ пустой, и в responseBody идет null

Comment: "оно" писать само никогда не будет. Вы где-то вставили отладочную печать? где? или это бросается исключение? в каком месте?

Comment: Это в дебаге видно, когда оно состояние каждой переменной показывает

Comment: если Future - Not completed, то метод get() еще не завершился, и responseBody не должно быть видно в окне дебаггера вообще.

Comment: и... следует добавить задержку? какой-нибудь sleep/wait?

Comment: для чего задержку?